# How To Check If SSH Is Installed On Jailbroken Phone? Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

Does anyone know how I can check within my app if SSH is installed on a jailbroken device?  I'm developing an enterprise (ad hoc) app and little paranoid about the data stored within the Documents directory and sqlite db.  If I can detect that ssh is installed, I'd like to delete all sensitive content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any way you could detect that it is installed is easily foiled.  Someone could simply change the name of the sshd for example.  If you're concerned about the data being stored on the user's device then encrypt it.  That will prevent someone from reading it directly.  It won't necessarily prevent them from being able to access the data at all, there's still process tracing and so forth that can be done, but you would be safe from all but a very skilled cracker.  If the data is so sensitive it can't be stored on a mobile device then don't store it there at all (or even deliver it to the device).  At some level you'll have to make a decision on just how secure the data needs to be...

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  You're absolutely correct.  But I don't see the harm in checking if SSH is installed as well.  It can be an additional security layer, no?

Comment: My point is exactly that it *isn't* an additional security layer, for the reason that it won't work as you intend.  Don't try to convince yourself to use an inappropriate/non-functional security system because it provides "some" additional assistance.  Decide instead what level of security you really need and choose an implementation that meets your goals.